# Composer rejected by your constraint

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to pull a specific branch from another package I am working on into a package. However I keep getting this error:

> The requested package tipoff/support dev-feature/#7-add-base-model-to-support-package exists as tipoff/support[dev-main, dev-feature/#7-add-base-model-to-support-package] but these are rejected by your constraint.

Here is my *composer.json* file

```json
{
    "name": "tipoff/fees",
    "description": "Laravel Package for implementing Ecommerce fees",
    "keywords": [
        "tipoff",
        "fees"
    ],
    "homepage": "https://github.com/tipoff/fees",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Tipoff",
            "email": "packages@tipoff.com",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4|^8.0",
        "spatie/laravel-package-tools": "^1.1",
        "illuminate/contracts": "^8.0",
        "tipoff/support": "dev-feature/#7-add-base-model-to-support-package"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "orchestra/testbench": "^6.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3",
        "spatie/laravel-ray": "^1.9"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tipoff\\Fees\\": "src",
            "Tipoff\\Fees\\Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tipoff\\Fees\\Tests\\": "tests"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "psalm": "vendor/bin/psalm",
        "test": "vendor/bin/phpunit --colors=always",
        "test-coverage": "vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html coverage"
    },
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "providers": [
                "Tipoff\\Fees\\FeesServiceProvider"
            ],
            "aliases": {
                "Fees": "Tipoff\\Fees\\FeesFacade"
            }
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/tipoff/support"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried to use an alias as I have seen in other answers regarding this issue. I followed https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/aliases.md but with no luck.

Can someone help me figure out what is going wrong?

Comment: This would be because hash in branch names are supposed to be for commit pinning. See https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5420 and more specifically https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5420#issuecomment-225366232

Answer (score 0):

The problem was having a # character in the branch name.